# Can a library be accessed from a project containing a library project that contains the library project which both are dependent on?

Tags: java, android, ant

I want to limit the size of my apk for distribution, and I need the android support library in it. I am also using a library project that my company uses for handling push notifications. Inside of this library project is the support library, since I need it for both my application, and the push library project, is it possible to access the android support library from both, if it is only contained in the libs folder of the library project, rather than including it in both libs directories (which seems wasteful)? Do I need to add it to my application's project.properties as a library, (I'm using ant (answers pertaining to eclipse are also welcome)) or can I just access it by importing the library as if it were in both locations. (obviously this does not work if I stick the library only in the libs folder of the overarching project). I could not find anything about this online, and I am looking to post an answer as soon as I find one so that others searching will find an answer quickly, if I find the answer before someone else gets to it (I will resist selecting my own answer, in order to allow people with a more detailed explanation of why it does or does not work to answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access the android support library from both, if it is only contained in the libs folder of the library project, rather than including it in both libs directories (which seems wasteful)?

Yes, though it's not wasteful. Android's build tools detect two copies of the same JAR (same name, same MD5) and only uses one. That's why you will get build errors if you update one copy and not the other.

Since apps gain access to library projects' JARs, you can safely remove the Android Support package JAR from your app.